# Play videos in c++ using QT creator

Tags: c++, windows, video, playback

I developing a game in C++ using SDL on windows 7 64 bits with Qt creator IDE. I need to play a video during the game. I already tried using smpeg.lib ( from de SDL itself), QtMobility API and OpenCV. But i failed with all of them. I really need a easy tutorial "how to play a video file of any format", using anything! It can even use the things that I already tried, but i really need a good tutorial.
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Qt Phonon`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/phonon-module.html) for playing video files. An official example can be found 
[here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/phonon-qmusicplayer.html)

The example is for playing audio files but phonon can play video files too..

HTH in giving you a start.